# Weblogic : show messages in a topic?

Tags: jms, weblogic

I have a event topic created in my Weblogic, which is of type Uniform Distributed Topic. I'd like to know how can I see the JMS messages in this topic ? Why I cannot find something like `showMessage` as it's in a queue ?

Answer (score 0):

Messages sent to a topic aren't actually stored in the topic itself. The messages are stored in the *subscriptions* on the topic. That's why there's no `showMessage` as a queue.

I don't have an installation of WebLogic handy, but you should be able to see the active subscriptions in the web console. From there you should be able to display the messages in the subscription.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, so where I can find the messages (subscription) in weblogic console or on the server ?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, no I don't find the subscriptions section in JMS server...

Comment: Are you certain there are active subscriptions? If so, are the subscriptions durable?

Comment: WebLogic does not use the "subscription" term but "subscriber" for a topic. To see incoming messages from a topic in the admin console, you need to pause the message consumtion on the topic otherwise messages are quickly read by consumers and you don't have the time to see it.
In the admin console go to the topic configuration. You will fnd an option to view its content